# selenium WebDriver зависает тест

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Добрый день господа. Мне опять нужна помощь))) 
Есть Три теста по авторизации на сайте через G+ Vk and Fb.
Тест заходит на сайт, нажимает войти. В открывшимся окне нажимает G+. Появляется еще окно. Там вводится логин и пароль и войти. Окно закрывается. Вот такая задача. Vk и Fb , а вот G+... Тест проходит, но тест зависает и висит и падает по тайм ауту( Три теста абсолютно одинаковы.

```
@Test
public void testLogGoogle() throws Exception    {

    String winHandleMain = Core.getDriver().getWindowHandle();



    getClickableElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/span/span")).click();  //Кликнуть Вход.

    getClickableElement(By.cssSelector("html.bx-core.bx-no-touch.bx-no-retina.bx-firefox body#main div.enter_frame.popup.jqmID5.show div#wrap_ajax_auth div#comp_16e6995f4a0af87d335aae3c5464ba93 div#ajax_auth div.reg-new div.soc-avt div.row.clearfix span.auth a.bx-ss-button.google-button i.soc-icon.google")).click();



    for(String winHandle : Core.getDriver().getWindowHandles()) {
        Core.getDriver().switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }


    getClickableElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"identifierId\"]")).clear();
    Core.getDriver().findElement(By.name("identifier")).sendKeys("###");
    getClickableElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"identifierNext\"]/content/span")).click();
    getClickableElement(By.name("password")).clear();
    getClickableElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("#####");

    getClickableElement(By.cssSelector("#passwordNext > content > span")).click();



    Core.getDriver().switchTo().window(winHandleMain);

}  введите сюда код
```

Comment: после авторизации в vk и fb поставьте дебагер и посмотрите на каком моменте зависает + при этом наблюдайте за браузером.

Comment: Ставил. Завис идет на последней строке. Он кликает и все. висит. показывает. что вошел, тест сработал, но браузер закрыть не дает. Почему виснет этот последний клик непонятно

Comment: Я начинающий ))) Код был найден на просторах сети. Но там объяснения, за что каждая строчка отвечает не было((( Может кто, если не поможет с кодом, то хоть растолкует подробно?

Comment: G+ перестал работать вроде об этом сообщалось в гугле.

Answer (score 0):

Браузер закрывается по команде `driver.quit()`

Буду писать по строкам.

```
1. Получить элемент на который можно кликнуть. используется xpath.
2. Получение текущего окна, так сказать адрес. После того можно переключатся на него по этой строке.
3. Получение всех адресов окон.
4, 5. Находим кнопку и кликаем. Важный момент. Если Элемент не найден будет эксепшн.
6. Ожидание окна которое должно открытся при клике на предыдущую кнопку. 
7. Переключение на основное окно.
8. Переключение на окно магазина.
9. Получение заголовка страницы
10. Очищение контента элемента (скорее всего это)
11. Вставка текста в поле типо input-а
12. дальше поиск, очистка, вставка и клик.
```

Я бы это:

```
for(String winHandle : Core.getDriver().getWindowHandles()) {
    Core.getDriver().switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
```

заменил на это:

```
for(String winHandle : Core.getDriver().getWindowHandles()) {
    if(!winHandle.equals(winHandleMain)) {
       Core.getDriver().switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробовал с новым кодом Vk все работает как по маслу.

Comment: Господа, я все еще жду ответ на вопрос)))

Comment: @СергейБогданов обновил ответ

Comment: Не вышло( Никаких изменений. Все, как было.

Comment: @СергейБогданов браузер какой?

Comment: Firefox. Тот же код отлично с Vk работает